# How to find and display specific data in SQL Database with C# code in UWP app?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, uwp

EDIT 2: Solved by using SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader

DISCLAIMER: I am complete beginner in using C# code for searching in SQL database, so I know practically nothing about this problem.

I was given a task to make a desktop app for searching a name of a product in a database based on its ID. The only thing I've successfully did was connecting the SQL database to the app via Visual Studio. [On this picture you can see the clearest description I am able to give.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNNZz.png)

I have absolutely no clue what to even try. I've seen some class called SqlConnection, but again, I am not completely sure if it could help me somehow.

I am sure that this is one of the most basic problems ever posted on this site, but I am completely stuck and don't know what to do next.

Thanks for anything in advance.

EDIT: Yeah, I forgot to mention one pretty important thing - I am making this as UWP app. Sorry for that.

Comment: What have you tried from your searches?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav 
>I have absolutely no clue what to even try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, please refer to [Use a SQLite database in a UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) app document. It has detail steps to use Microsoft.Data.SQLite  to load the database with specific table-command.

> searching a name of a product in a database based on its ID.

```
SELECT * FROM [tb-name] WHERE [id]=@id"


selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "id-value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to setup some connection for your database,
Add this line to your web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="myDbConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

and then if you design UI Part, then
call this function after button click on your UI,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //data soure control that works with sql database
        SqlDataSource sds = new SqlDataSource();
        //get connection string from application's web.config file
        sds.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDbConnectionString1"].ToString();
        //create parameters with specified name and values
        sds.SelectParameters.Add("name", TypeCode.String, this.TextBox1.Text);
        //set the sql string to retrive data from the database
        sds.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [myTb] WHERE [name]=@name";
        //retrive data
        DataView dv = (DataView)sds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        if (dv.Count == 0)
        {
            this.Label1.Text = "No Data Found";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = sds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention one pretty important thing - I am making this as UWP app. Sorry for that.